# PYTHON - Copy entire row with formatting

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am new in Python and Openpyxl.
I am trying to copy a range of cells (with their formatting knowing some cells are merged) from a row to an other row on the same worksheet.

Thanks

Comment: Folks will usually respond better and more easily if you can demonstrate what you have worked on so far for the problem and where you are stuck. That said, a decent place to start with an Excel question like this is to actually record a macro in Excel that does what you are trying to do and then examine that macro code and port it over to python/Openpyxl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example to copy cells from one row to another within the same worksheet.
This example takes a range of cells on row 2 from column A to column column J and duplicates to 'row_offset' rows down, in this case row 12. The duplication includes cell style/formatting and merged cells.

```
from openpyxl.utils import rows_from_range
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange
from copy import copy


def copy_range(range_str, sheet, offset):
    """ Copy cell values and style to the new row using offset"""
    for row in rows_from_range(range_str):
        for cell in row:
            if sheet[cell].value is not None:  # Don't copy other cells in merged unit
                dst_cell = sheet[cell].offset(row=offset, column=0)
                src_cell = sheet[cell]

                ### Copy Cell value
                dst_cell.value = src_cell.value

                ### Copy Cell Styles
                dst_cell.font = copy(src_cell.font)
                dst_cell.alignment = copy(src_cell.alignment)
                dst_cell.border = copy(src_cell.border)
                dst_cell.fill = copy(src_cell.fill)

                dst_cell.number_format = src_cell.number_format


def get_merge_list(r_range, r_offset):
    """ Create a list of new cell merges from the existing row"""
    area = CellRange(r_range)  # Range to check for merged cells
    mlist = []  # List of merged cells on existing row offset to the new row
    for mc in ws.merged_cells:
        if mc.coord not in area:
            continue
        cr = CellRange(mc.coord)
        cr.shift(row_shift=r_offset)
        mlist.append(cr.coord)

    return mlist


wb = load_workbook("foo.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']

row_range = 'A2:J2'  # Row range to be copied
row_offset = 10  # Offset to the new row

### Create a range list for merged cells on new row
new_merge_list = get_merge_list(row_range, row_offset)
### Create merged cells on new row
for nm in new_merge_list:
    ws.merge_cells(nm)

### Copy cell values to new row
copy_range(row_range, ws, row_offset)

### Save workbook
wb.save("foo_out.xlsx")
```

[image]